# css filter display issue in blogger with internet explorer

Tags: html, css, blogger, display

I have a blogger blog for several years and I have some concerns about a CSS filter.

I like to have your opinion on it.

- Question No. 1 -

I use a CSS filter in the blogger template to edit animated GIF (hue, saturation, brightness ...) in the bottom of my blog (see below).

```
.filter-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9999;
}

body#layout .filter-wrapper {
  position: relative !important;
}

body#layout #fb-root {
  position: relative !important;
}

#fb-root {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  background-image: url(https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-REJ8pezTyCQ/SDlvLzhAH-I/AAAAAAAABeQ/mC1PXNiheJU/s800/Blog_background_750.gif);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-filter: blur(9px) brightness(25%) sepia(88%) hue-rotate(125deg) saturate(344%);
  -moz-filter: blur(9px) brightness(25%) sepia(88%) hue-rotate(125deg) saturate(344%);
  -o-filter: blur(9px) brightness(25%) sepia(88%) hue-rotate(125deg) saturate(344%);
  -ms-filter: blur(9px) brightness(25%) sepia(88%) hue-rotate(125deg) saturate(344%);
  filter: blur(9px) brightness(25%) sepia(88%) hue-rotate(125deg) saturate(344%);
}
```

The CSS filter works perfectly on all web browsers like Chrome, Mozilla, Safari ... etc.

However, when using Internet Explorer filter which I speak above no longer works. I tried to find information about it unfortunately after much research I concluded that certain functions of the filter I use are disabled on IE.

Being rather novice in CSS and in internet browsers architecture I'd like to have your opinion about it.

Might there be ways to achieve the same result for my background in IE than on other browsers.

And if so, what would they be?

- Question No. 2 -

In addition to the filter settings I noticed that there were lines associated with different browser.

moz-filter: -------> for Mozilla Firefox

o-filter:      -------> I guess for Opera

ms-filter:   -------> for MS Internet Explorer ?

But when I change the values of these lines associated with different browsers I see no change, is this normal?
I joined the html template.

Thank you for your attention and your time.

Comment: IE only supports filter with SVG, not html  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2011/10/14/svg-filter-effects-in-ie10/  http://caniuse.com/#search=filter

Comment: Please fix that formatting!

Answer (score 1):

Using https://github.com/iamvdo/pleeease-filters, I was able to convert CSS Filter to their SVG equivalent

```
filter: blur(9px) brightness(25%) sepia(88%) hue-rotate(125deg) saturate(344%);
```

Was converted to

```
filter: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><filter id="filtersPicture"><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="9" /><feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"><feFuncR type="linear" slope="0.25" /><feFuncG type="linear" slope="0.25" /><feFuncB type="linear" slope="0.25" /></feComponentTransfer><feColorMatrix type="matrix" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" values="0.46584000000000003 0.67672 0.16632 0 0 0.30712 0.7236800000000001 0.14784 0 0 0.23936000000000002 0.46992 0.23528 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" /><feColorMatrix type="hueRotate" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" values="125" /><feColorMatrix type="matrix" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" values="2.92028 -1.7446000000000002 -0.17568 0 0 -0.51972 1.7298 -0.17568 0 0 -0.51972 -1.7446000000000002 3.26432 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" /></filter></svg>');
```

But this didn't work in IE11.

A possible alternative to this would be [CSS Filters Polyfill](https://github.com/Schepp/CSS-Filters-Polyfill), which could make it work with IE, but there are a few caveats -

1. Firstly it didn't support `hue-rotate` and `saturate` filters so it wouldn't produce the same effects.
2. It only worked for IE 6-9. IE 10+ browsers were not supported. Which doesn't make it useful as now Microsoft only recommends (and supports) using IE11 - [Internet Explorer End of Support](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support)

The reason why this polyfill doesn't work for Internet Explorer 11 is because none of the filter format work in it. The older format supported by IE 6-9 got removed from it (Refer to [-ms-filter property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530752(v=vs.85).aspx)) and the CSS Filters implemented by all the other browsers never got implemented in it.

Therefore, the only way to make Filter work on IE 10-11 is by creating a proper SVG element and then applying SVG filters on it (That is the reason why the above SVG filter didn't work because it was specified inside CSS.)

Created an SVG element with the filters and the image.

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <filter id="filtersPicture">
            <feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"><feFuncR type="linear" slope="0.25"></feFuncR><feFuncG type="linear" slope="0.25"></feFuncG><feFuncB type="linear" slope="0.25"></feFuncB></feComponentTransfer><feColorMatrix type="matrix" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" values="0.46584000000000003 0.67672 0.16632 0 0 0.30712 0.7236800000000001 0.14784 0 0 0.23936000000000002 0.46992 0.23528 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"></feColorMatrix><feColorMatrix type="hueRotate" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" values="125"></feColorMatrix><feColorMatrix type="matrix" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" values="2.92028 -1.7446000000000002 -0.17568 0 0 -0.51972 1.7298 -0.17568 0 0 -0.51972 -1.7446000000000002 3.26432 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"></feColorMatrix>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <image filter="url(&quot;#filtersPicture&quot;)" x="0" y="0" width="750" height="750" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-REJ8pezTyCQ/SDlvLzhAH-I/AAAAAAAABeQ/mC1PXNiheJU/s800/Blog_background_750.gif"></image>
</svg>
```

Also, now Microsoft has shipped the Edge browser on newer Windows 10. It does support CSS Filters but they need to be switched on via a flag (Refer to [Learn how to use CSS3 Filters](https://dev.windows.com/pt-pt/microsoft-edge/testdrive/demos/css3filters/)).

A bit unrelated, Full-screen GIF and CSS Filters together can be very slow. Refer to [CSS filters, GIFs, and performance](https://medium.com/@glenmaddern/css-filters-gifs-and-performance-4364221d6d97#18e3).